# Swedish train operators that allow assembled bikes

Tags: trains, sweden, bicycles

Is there an overview of train lines which carry bicycles without having to disassemble them? I traveled by train from Malmö to Gothenburg last year and it was super easy to take the bicycle with me on the train. However, it's being said that this is not the case for all train lines in Sweden. Is there an overview on which train lines bicycles can be taken along easily?

Answer (score 3):

The local branch Naturskyddsföreningen (Swedish Society for Nature Conservation) in Lund has made an [overview](https://lund.naturskyddsforeningen.se/wp-content/uploads/sites/130/2021/05/Cykel_pa_tag_maj_2021_Naturskyddsforeningen.pdf) for the season of 2021. It is in Swedish. The map overview is nice but one route can have several operators with different rules so one needs to make some research to know which train companies on the route that accepts bikes.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: I'm guessing you found this through https://swedenbybike.com/en/ which seems like a great site for tourists to check out (I'm not affiliated).